# My Language And Region doesnt work?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, regional-settings, language-pack

I have a SP2016 installation with language packs installed. Now I wanted to change my preferred language and Region so SharePoint uses that instead of the default language of my browser settings. When I click "My Settings" and then "My Language And Region", the page just refreshes and nothing seems to happen.

I have checked my user's permisson and I give it all permission but didnt change anything. I know ı can change language and Region other ways. But I have to reach from there

So Any ideas would we welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What is your base languge( sharepoint install) and which additonal LPs installed? what you think should be change?

Comment: I have installed it in English.  We have many users which using different language (German, Turkish, Russian, Japanese and Arabic). So I have to manage it for each user. But When I wanted to reach Language and Region of my browser settings, it just refresh the page. Why doesnt it work ? I have checked the permission, even though the user has full control permission , the issue is still same.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the Language settings directly via: /_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx